# Jsoup unable to Fetch required data from Html Tag

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I have a scenario where a `div` tag contains three tables, and all three tables look like a single table in the UI.

I am using **Jsoup Parser** to parse the tables and fetch table data. However, Jsoup returns only the first two tables; the third table is not parsed, even though the markup for the table is present in the same `div` tag in which the first two tables are contained.

Here's the code I use to gather the `table` elements:

```
//getting outer html
html = div.getAttribute("outerHTML");

source = Jsoup.parse(html, "UTF-8");
tableList = source.select("table");
System.out.println("NO OF TABLES OBTAINED IS:--> " + tableList.size());
```

The above code should have returned `3` as the tableList size, but it only returns `2`.

Comment: Can you show us the html fragment that you are trying to parse?

Comment: It sounds like HTML you are parsing is corrupted. Please post in your question what the HTML you are parsing looks like.

Comment: next to @SzymonStepniak's suggestion, it is also possible that the 3rd table is generated by JavaScript dynamically, e.g. with data from an AJAX call. In that case you can't use JSoup, since it does not run JavaScript